# Как лучше обернуть выражение в функцию python

Tags: python

Всем привет ! Возник такой вопрос:Как этот кусок кода лучше обернуть в функцию которая будет вызывать все функции?

Есть такой код:

```
# < Цикл для перебора из кортежа.
    for resource in resources:
        resource_name = resource[1]
        resource_link = resource[2]
        resource_url = resource[3]
        link_rule = resource[4]
        title_rule = resource[5]
        datetime_rule = resource[6]
        datetime1_rule = resource[7]
        text_rule = resource[8]
        text1_rule = resource[9]
        print(resource_name)
        resource_domain=resource_link
        # < Разбиваю данные из кортежа в массив.
        links_rule = link_rule.split(',')
        title_rule = title_rule.split(',')
        datetime_rule = datetime_rule.split(',')
        datetime1_rule = datetime1_rule.split(',')
        text_rule = text_rule.split(',')
        text1_rule = text1_rule.split(',')
        resource_page = get_html(resource_url)
        resource_links = get_resource_links(resource_page,links_rule,resource_domain)
        print('кол-во ссылок: '+str(len(resource_links)))

        # < Цикл для вызова функции.
        for resource_link in resource_links:
            item_page = get_html(resource_link)
            item_title = get_item_title(item_page,title_rule)
            item_datetime = get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule)
            item_text_content = get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule)

            try:
                # < Запись новостей в БД.
                sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                cursor=connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
                print('Запись в базу данных успешно завершена!')
            except pymysql.err.IntegrityError:
                print('ah shit ! duplicate error!')
                break
            except pymysql.err.InternalError:
                print('ah shit ! error')
                break
```

Прошу не кидаться камнями.

Comment: `resource[0]` у вас не используется?

Comment: `resource[0]` не используется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ.Вот так лучше оборачивать:

```
def call_all_func(resources):
    # < Цикл для перебора из кортежа.
    for resource in resources:
        resource_name = resource[1]
        resource_link = resource[2]
        resource_url = resource[3]
        link_rule = resource[4]
        title_rule = resource[5]
        datetime_rule = resource[6]
        datetime1_rule = resource[7]
        text_rule = resource[8]
        text1_rule = resource[9]
        print(resource_name)
        resource_domain=resource_link
        # < Разбиваю данные из кортежа в массив.
        links_rule = link_rule.split(',')
        title_rule = title_rule.split(',')
        datetime_rule = datetime_rule.split(',')
        datetime1_rule = datetime1_rule.split(',')
        text_rule = text_rule.split(',')
        text1_rule = text1_rule.split(',')
        resource_page = get_html(resource_url)
        resource_links = get_resource_links(resource_page,links_rule,resource_domain)
        print('кол-во ссылок: '+str(len(resource_links)))

        # < Цикл для вызова функции.
        for resource_link in resource_links:
            item_page = get_html(resource_link)
            item_title = get_item_title(item_page,title_rule)
            item_datetime = get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule)
            item_text_content = get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule)

            try:
                # < Запись новостей в БД.
                sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                cursor=connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
                print('Запись в базу данных успешно завершена!')
            except pymysql.err.IntegrityError:
                print('ah shit ! duplicate error!')
                break
            except pymysql.err.InternalError:
                print('ah shit ! error')
                break

call_all_func(resources)
```